# Joomla module for adding HTML table grid with the ability to instantly search the content of the table only

Tags: search, joomla

I am trying to find a Joomla module so I can instantly search the content of the table grid and see the results instantly.

As an example, if you have a table, by default all rows are shown; however, as you type in the search box, the table rows decrease... only the matching rows are shown on the page.

I came across a similar module but only for the Wordpress. I need a similar module for Joomla instead.

[Here is the Wordpress version](http://tobias.baethge.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-table-reloaded-english/)

Comment: you'll probably find what you're looking for here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/tables-a-lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use JUMI to embed custom PHP code in a module or component position and DataTables to build your table grid. Here are the links :

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023

http://www.datatables.net/

I use both of them in a personal project and it's working like a charm